# Eclipse: The type VertexNotFoundException could not be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compiler-errors

I'm working on some code for a class project. We're given a .jar file with some classes we need to use. In using those classes, I encountered quite an error. One of the classes, a directional graph, has a method for adding an edge between two nodes in a graph. That method throws a VertexNotFoundException, defined in one of the .class files in the jar we were given. Whenever I try to use that method, I get the error listed in the title: `The type VertexNotFoundException could not be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`. I added the jar to my project by going through Build Path->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jar and selecting this jar. The directed graph class, also found in the jar, works fine, yet VertexNotFoundException does not.

Note that I do not directly reference VertexNotFoundException in my code, but I use code which references it.

A little bit (the first two pages) of googling revealed that this error message likes to pop up when people don't include certain Apache jars in their Apache project, yet I am not using Apache for this project and have no need to do any server things at all. I also found that this error likes to happen with some classes from the Java runtime itself, but that was supposedly fixed in Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

-1 because this didn't work, but I use www.findjar.com Type in the class and it will (most of the time) list JAR that contain it. I tried it with your class, which the site recognizes, but it didn't know of any JAR.

Comment: Well, like I said, the JAR was provided by my instructor, so I wouldn't expect to find it elsewhere. Also, I have the JAR.